# Is it possible to override / bypass nscd?

Tags: c, linux, unix, nss

I am making an NSS module answers depending on the name of the caller. For example, if *sshd* calls `getpwnam_r(...)`, the `pw_shell` will be */bin/bash*; if *telnetd* calls `getpwnam_r(...)`, the `pw_shell` will be */bin/ksh*.

A prototype is made and it works. However, when *nscd* is running and the cache is hot, the module's function will not be called. *nscd*'s cached result is returned to every caller. *nscd* assumes the only variable to the result is time; it never think of process name will affect the result.

Suppose we can make some daemon or module to override *nscd*, the code should check the process name is on my list or not. If it is on the list, skip *nscd*; otherwise, let *nscd* answer `getpwnam_r(...)`.

Is it possible?

---

Edit: Less preferable, but OK alternative is to bypass *nscd* when call `getpwnam_r(...)`.

Comment: I think that if you really require this behavior your best bet is to simply disable `nscd` and see if you notice a performance hit.  Many people run happily with nscd disabled; it all depends on the size of your environment.

Comment: I have little control on this. The environment varies. Most likely the users want *nscd*.

Answer (score 1):

The calls to nscd are hardwired into the standard library such that any call to a map-related function (getpwnam(), gethostbyname() etc...) will query nscd first. The only solution is to turn nscd off or to write your own.

You can confirm this by using getent and strace:

strace -ttt getent passwd

Others have written nscd replacements - gnscd by Google, unscd for BusyBox.
So if you cannot disable nscd then you must rewrite it....

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It **is** possible to bypass *nscd* on a per-process basis, although it's a bit of a hack.

If you check out the *glibc* source code you'll observe there's a function called *__nss_disable_nscd*.  This is used by *nscd* (or *unscd*) to ensure that it doesn't go recursive.

Probably easier to read the example in *unscd*.  See http://busybox.net/~vda/unscd/nscd-0.51.c